# max-width does not have effect on iPhone

Tags: iphone, html, resolution, css

I am trying to make my webpage appear with page width equal to that of a phone screen.  So, for example, the resolution of the html page would be the resolution of the phone screen viewing it.  If it's viewed on computer, I want it to be shown in a div with white boarders on the side.  So, I did this in my CSS:

```
html {
  max-width: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

but then the whole page just zoomed out on the iPhone screen, when the iphone screen has width less than 400px?  Why?  How can I fix this?

**Update - screenshot as below.**
[image]

Comment: Why not use width:100%?

Comment: @BingeBoy because when the page is viewed on larger screens (e.g. tablet / computer) I don't want them to see the whole content zoomed in really big.

Comment: You could use a media query and make the page responsive.

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/8KwVE/2/

You could try messing around with a responsive theme.

HTML

```
<head>
//other stuff
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
</head>
```

CSS

```
//iphone is horizontal
@media only screen and (max-width : 480px) {
    body{
        width:100%;
    }
    //other code!
}
//iphone is vertical
@media only screen and (max-width : 320px) {
    body{
        width:100%;
    }
    //other code!
}
```